# Converting date between DD/MM/YYYY and YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: python, date

Using a Python script, I need to read a CVS file where dates are formated as DD/MM/YYYY, and convert them to YYYY-MM-DD before saving this into a SQLite database.

This almost works, but fails because I don't provide time:

```
from datetime import datetime

lastconnection = datetime.strptime("21/12/2008", "%Y-%m-%d")

#ValueError: time data did not match format:  data=21/12/2008  fmt=%Y-%m-%d
print lastconnection
```

I assume there's a method in the datetime object to perform this conversion very easily, but I can't find an example of how to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 125):

Your example code is wrong. This works:

```
import datetime

datetime.datetime.strptime("21/12/2008", "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

The call to strptime() parses the first argument according to the format specified in the second, so those two need to match. Then you can call strftime() to format the result into the desired final format.

Comment: can it be implemented into pandas ?

Comment: @Basile you can. 

pd.to_datetime(df['your_date_column'], format='%d/%m/%Y').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

Answer (score 23):

you first would need to convert string into datetime tuple, and then convert that datetime tuple to string, it would go like this:

```
lastconnection = datetime.strptime("21/12/2008", "%d/%m/%Y").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Saying "tuple" seems a bit confusing; as of Python 2.2, `strptime()` [returns "a `struct_time`"](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime), which [is an object](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.struct_time) with a "named tuple" interface.

Answer (score 18):

I am new to programming.  I wanted to convert from `yyyy-mm-dd` to `dd/mm/yyyy` to print out a date in the format that people in my part of the world use and recognise.

The accepted answer above got me on the right track.

The answer I ended up with to my problem is:

```
import datetime

today_date = datetime.date.today()
print(today_date)

new_today_date = today_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
print (new_today_date)
```

The first two lines after the import statement gives today's date in the USA format (2017-01-26).  The last two lines convert this to the format recognised in the UK and other countries (26/01/2017).

You can shorten this code, but I left it as is because it is helpful to me as a beginner.  I hope this helps other beginner programmers starting out!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Your answer does not really go with the question, which was about a conversion from `DD/MM/YYYY` to `YYYY-MM-DD`.Your post may be deleted, however I encourage you to keep yourself active in the site. Thanks!

Comment: @lrnzcig Thank you for your comment.  I see what you mean.  Perhaps i should have posted my question and let someone answer it - I've had lots of questions so far, but i've managed to answer them by looking online and in my trusty python book

Answer (score 10):

Does anyone else else think it's a waste to convert these strings to date/time objects for what is, in the end, a simple text transformation? If you're certain the incoming dates will be valid, you can just use:

```
>>> ddmmyyyy = "21/12/2008"
>>> yyyymmdd = ddmmyyyy[6:] + "-" + ddmmyyyy[3:5] + "-" + ddmmyyyy[:2]
>>> yyyymmdd
'2008-12-21'
```

This will almost certainly be faster than the conversion to and from a date.

Comment: If you're worried about the speed of converting to date the you clearly have nothing else left to worry about it. The code posted by unwind is so much clearer and maintainable than yours. That should be your primary concern here, not speed.

Comment: If you're looping over 200,000 records like I am, then performance matters.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to convert an entire column (from `pandas` `DataFrame`), first convert it (`pandas` `Series`) to the `datetime` format using `to_datetime` and then use `.dt.strftime`:

```
def conv_dates_series(df, col, old_date_format, new_date_format):

    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], format=old_date_format).dt.strftime(new_date_format)
    
    return df
```

###### Sample usage:

```
import pandas as pd

test_df = pd.DataFrame({"Dates": ["1900-01-01", "1999-12-31"]})

old_date_format='%Y-%m-%d'
new_date_format='%d/%m/%Y'

conv_dates_series(test_df, "Dates", old_date_format, new_date_format)

    Dates
0   01/01/1900
1   31/12/1999
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#case_date= 03/31/2020   

#Above is the value stored in case_date in format(mm/dd/yyyy )

demo=case_date.split("/")
new_case_date = demo[1]+"-"+demo[0]+"-"+demo[2]
#new format of date is (dd/mm/yyyy) test by printing it 
print(new_case_date)
```

Answer (score 2):

The most simplest way

While reading the csv file, put an argument `parse_dates`

```py
df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv", parse_dates=['column_name'])
```

This will convert the dates of mentioned column to YYYY-MM-DD format

Answer (score 0):

Convert date format DD/MM/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD according to your question, you can use this:

```
from datetime import datetime
lastconnection = datetime.strptime("21/12/2008", "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(lastconnection)
```

Answer (score 0):

- `df` is your data frame
- `Dateclm` is the column that you want to change

This column should be in `DateTime` datatype.

```
df['Dateclm'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dateclm'])

df.dtypes


#Here is the solution to change the format of the column

df["Dateclm"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Dateclm"]).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print(df)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).