# Python 3.6 csv str type date or time.struct_time type compare to datetime.date data type

Tags: python-3.x, csv, date, type-conversion

I have a csv file with a date column. I want to compare that date with the current date. When I use the time module to get the current date it is a datetime.date type, but when I use the conversion method @unwind posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502726/converting-date-between-dd-mm-yyyy-and-yyyy-mm-dd) the data type of my column is time.struct_time and I receive an error.

```
import csv
import time
from datetime import datetime
import uuid
present = datetime.today().date()
with open(r'FilePath','r',newline='') as f:
        # skip header line
        next(f)
        r = csv.reader(f)
        for row in r:
            if len(row[29])>1:
                newdate2 = time.strptime(row[29], "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/FilePath/DateCompare.py", line 15, in <module>
    newdate2 = time.strptime(row[29], "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
AttributeError: 'time.struct_time' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

The indexes can be combined into a string, but I can't figure out how to convert to datetime.date to compare.

Convert column to formatted string:

```
import csv
import time
from datetime import datetime
import uuid
present = datetime.today().date()

with open(r'FilePath','r',newline='') as f:
        # skip header line
        next(f)
        r = csv.reader(f)
        for row in r:
            if len(row[29])>1:
                newdate2 = time.strptime(row[29], "%m/%d/%Y")
                newdate3 = ('{}-{}-{}'.format(newdate2[0],newdate2[1],newdate2[2]))
```

Sample String Output:

```
2018-2-1
2018-2-1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using .now() instead of .today.date got my "present" variable into datetime.datetime format and using datetime.strptime(row[29], "%m/%d/%Y") got my cell value into datetime.datetime so that I could compare the current date to the dates in the file.

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
present = datetime.now()
with open(r'InputFilePath','r',newline='') as f:
    with open(r'DestinationFilePath','w', newline ='') as f1:
        next(f)
        w = csv.writer (f1)
        r = csv.reader(f)
        for row in r:
            if len(row[29])>1:
                newdate2 = datetime.strptime(row[29], "%m/%d/%Y")
                row[29] = newdate2
                if row[29]>present:
                    w.writerow(row)
                else:
                    continue
```