# Convert data from datetime format in format dd.mm.YYYY in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, backend

I need to take data from my database and send it to the front, but the problem is that they come in datetime.date(2021,11,8) format, and I need to send them in 08.11.2021 format. Tell me how to do this? I use sqlaclhemy core.

`s = select([report.c.id, report.c.created_at, report.c.filename, report.c.filepath, report.c.period_type, report.c.reporting_period, report.c.sign_at, report.c.is_deleted, author,organization, category]).select_from(j).where(report.c.is_deleted == False).order_by(report.c.id)`  `

Output:
`'created_at': datetime.date(2021, 10, 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert dates to the dd.mm.yyyy format, use:

```
result = date.strftime("%d.%.m.%Y")
```

Source: [Converting date between DD/MM/YYYY and YYYY-MM-DD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502726/converting-date-between-dd-mm-yyyy-and-yyyy-mm-dd)

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
# lets say d = datetime.date(2021, 10, 1)
>>> d.strftime('%d.%m.%y')
```

```
Output: '1.10.2021'
```